# Typedef of a type defined in a separate header file

Tags: c, struct, header, typedef, software-design

I have two header files:

`src/util/buffer.h`:

```
//Namespace Src Util Buffer sub

struct sub_buffer{
    size_t size;
    void *buf;
};

//tons of static inline functions
```

`src/lib_context.h`:

```
   //Namespace Src Lib Context slc

   typedef struct sub_buffer slc_buffer; // Is this typedef ok?

   struct slc_context{
      //definition
   };

   void slc_set_buffer(slc_buffer *buf_ptr);

   //tons of other structs and functions
```

The thing that I was not sure about was the `typedef struct sub_buffer slc_buffer;`. There was a choice to include the `src/util/buffer.h`, but that would intoroduce tightly coupling to the header and it would be more difficult to replace it with e.g. another buffer definition containing flexible array member.

Is it common to introduce such a `typedef` to the structure that is defined in another header file so its implementation will be provided in the `c` file when including the header (but not to include one header to another header file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be an error.

You probably meant

```
typedef struct sub_buffer slc_buffer;
```

in which case it's fine, you can always introduce typedef aliases to types, even without having those types defined in the scope you're in.

This is the reason the classical self-referencing "node" works:

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
  node *next;
  void *data;
};
```

Notice how on the first line a `typedef` for an unknown type is used.

Comment: So roughly speaking we can use `typedef struct sub_buffer slc_buffer;` to abstract over tag name and the type used in the implementation. I mean if we decide to use another type we just change the typedef to `typedef union another_fancy_buffer_implementation slc_buffer;` and provide the definition in the corresponding `c` file. The clients of the header do not require any changes... Is that correct?

Comment: @St.Antario — basically correct. As long as the function interfaces only use pointers to the incomplete or opaque type, there’s no problem.